# node js download vs filestream

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my nodejs code, I currently found two ways to download a file, they both works, but using different functions: download or file streaming. So what is the difference? which one is better? :

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res, next){
  res.download("uploads/123.txt");
}
```

or

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res, next){

    var file = __dirname + '/uploads/123.txt';
    var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);

    var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);
    res.setheader('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + '123.txt');
    res.setheader('content-type', mimetype);

    filestream.pipe(res);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.download` is a helper function used by express. It uses [`sendFile()`](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.sendFile), which uses basically the code you have in your second example. So whatever you use, what happens under the hood is the same.

So it will be easier for you to just use `res.download` - why write code double...